# Check User Credentials

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a question. I don’t understand how can I solve this problem. 
Basically, in my app, I have the first page `App.js` in which I defined the `<Router>` and `<Scenes>` (from `router-flux` library).

My problem is that I would like to check the credentials of the users, to change the navbar for the user’s role. In particular, if the user has the role `ROLE_PLUS` I don’t want to show the logout text (in the navbar) in the homepage.

But there I found a problem because I can easily recover the role of the user, but the problem is the navbar on the homepage is loaded first.

At the moment, I have created a flag with the Role: `ROLE_PLUS`, in this way if the role of the user logged in is different from this, I change this flag. But it doesn’t work properly because of the `render()` is executed first.

How can I do in your opinion? Thank you so much.

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      flag: 'ROLE_PLUS'
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.checkUser()
    }
  checkUser(){
    User.getUserLogged()
        .then(dataUserLogged => {   
          if (dataUserLogged !== null) {
            global.user = new User(JSON.parse(dataUserLogged));
            console.log("1) User Role: " + global.user.data.Roles)
            if(global.user.data.Roles != "ROLE_PLUS") {
              this.setState ({ flag: ‘ROLE_NORMAL’})
              console.log("2) New Flag: " + this.state.flag)
            }
          } })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        })
      }


  render() {
    console.log("3) FLAG: " + this.state.flag)    
    return (     
      <Router>
        <Scene key="root">
          //…
           <Scene
            key="homepage"
            component={Homepage}
            type="reset"
            rightTitle={ (this.state.flag != 'ROLE_PLUS')  ? "Logout" : ""}
            onRight={
              (this.state.flag != 'ROLE_PLUS' ) 
              ? () => Actions.refresh(App.logout())
              : () => {}
            }
            />

         //…
```

The console order print is: (3) - (1) - (2)

Answer (score 0):

You should use shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) lifecycle method instead of component did mount. Inside the shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) method write  your function and at the end return true.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    this.checkUser();
    return true;
}
```

Hope this will help. If you want to know more about react component life-cycle methods read [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

Update: 
After looking sometime, I have found another workaround. You should define the checkUser as checkUser = functoin() { your method }. And call that checkUser method from the beginning of render() method. Let me know if this workaround works for you.

```
checkUser = function(){
User.getUserLogged()
    .then(dataUserLogged => {   
      if (dataUserLogged !== null) {
        global.user = new User(JSON.parse(dataUserLogged));
        console.log("1) User Role: " + global.user.data.Roles)
        if(global.user.data.Roles != "ROLE_PLUS") {
          this.setState ({ flag: ‘ROLE_NORMAL’})
          console.log("2) New Flag: " + this.state.flag)
        }
      } })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    })
  }

    render() { 
        this.checkUser();
        .......your code......
   }
```

Comment: @InsomiacSabbir Thank you for your reply! Using this method I saw that the console.log inside the CheckUser function are not print.

Comment: Okay let me check and get back to you.

Comment: When I use this component, What is inside is not performed

Comment: I don't understand why If I change the role ( to ROLE_NORMAL ) I don't see the text Logout anyway...Anyway the function checkUser() goes in loop

Comment: @Jack23, can you elaborate the question please?

Comment: I think I got your problem. Let me clarify first, You mean when you set the user type to ROLE_NORMAL you can not see the logout text on your menu? In that case the reason is your component is not updating after you are changing the state.

Comment: exactly, when I log in with a user that has a role different than ROLE_PLUS, I still don't see the logout text. Do you know how can I solve? I'm going crazy

Comment: Did you check if the state flag is set before the render method returns the value? DId you see my updated code?

Comment: Yes I saw, and it works but the flag is set after the render method

Comment: @InsomiacSabbir if I print in the render "this.state.flag" it prints the "ROLE_PLUS"

Comment: can you please be specific about what you want to know? Like, fo you want to know what is going under the hood? And if my answer does solve your problem please mark it as correct. If you want to discuss this anymore feel free to knock me at sabbiralam.cse@gmail.com